# Why after running a server socket and using shutdown() do I have a file in that directory?

Tags: c, sockets

So I am making a basic server and client program in C and after I run the program I end up with a really weirdly named file that I have to remove for the program to work again. I assume that I am closing the sockets incorrectly. Currently I am closing the sockets as follows:

```
shutdown(serverSocket, SHUT_RDWR);
shutdown(clientSocket, SHUT_RDWR);
```

Any idea on why this is occuring?

Edit: both of these functions are returning 0

Here is the code that is causing the issue:

```
    char buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    int serverSocket = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server.sin_family = AF_LOCAL;
    server.sin_port = htons(54164);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
```

The file doesn't appear until I run the bind function.

Comment: What's the file called? Also, does your program make any files normally? Because I doubt it's anything to do with sockets.

Comment: Also, `shutdown` doesn't close a socket.

Comment: 'Ӕ?' is the name of the file. I do not modify files in any way for my program.

Comment: You say that you "assume" incorrect closing of sockets.  Have you tested your hypothesis by _not_ calling `shutdown` and observing if a file is created?  You might need to show a bit more code than just the `shutdown` calls.

Comment: @paddy I updated my question. It is the bind function that "creates" the phantom file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong socket address structure.  You are using `struct sockaddr_in` (which is for `AF_INET` family).

But when using the `AF_LOCAL` (a.k.a. `AF_UNIX`) family, `bind` is expecting you to pass a `struct sockaddr_un`, which specifies a path to your socket (in the file system).

According to the [manpage for unix sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

> A UNIX domain socket address is represented in the following structure:
>
> ```
> struct sockaddr_un {
>     sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
>     char        sun_path[108];            /* pathname */
> };
> ```
>
> The sun_family field always contains AF_UNIX.  On Linux sun_path is 108 bytes in size.

Additionally:

> Binding to a socket with a filename creates a socket in the
>          filesystem that must be deleted by the caller when it is no longer
>          needed (using **unlink**(2)).  The usual UNIX close-behind semantics
>          apply; the socket can be unlinked at any time and will be finally
>          removed from the filesystem when the last reference to it is closed.

Comment: So now I am trying to bind using the struct you suggested but my compiler says that the storage size for client and server are unknown...

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Hadn't included the std/un.h